# continuity of a bilinear form

Tags: functional-analysis

let $\Omega = ]0,1[$ end let $H = \{p \in H^1(\Omega), p(1)=0\}.$ And let $a \in L^{\infty}(\Omega).$

We consider $$l(w,v) = w(0) v(0) + \int_0^1 w' v' dx + \int_0^1 a(x) w(x) v(x) dx, \qquad \forall w , v \in H$$

-My question is how we prove that a is continue on $H \times H?$

For this, we must prove that there exist $M > 0$ such that $$|l(w,v)| \leq M ||w||_H ||v||_H$$ but I'm stuck, I do not know what to use for this proof.

Thank's for help.

Comment: Who's trace inequality?

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake.

Comment: Okay, so how we can prove continuity?

Comment: Where is the problem? Try to estimate each of the three addends.

Comment: my problem is how we can estimatimate $\int w' v'?$ and wy $w(0) v(0)$ is continuous?

Comment: For the derivative term, just use Young's inequality. Not sure about the $w(0)y(0).$